# Is there any string syntax in Ruby that allows interpolation but no escape character?

Tags: ruby

Is there any single-line string literal syntax in Ruby that allows string interpolation but does not interpret a backslash as an escape character?

I.e.,

Where `ruby_var = "foo"`

I want to be able to type the equivalent of `C:\some\windows\path\#{ruby_var}\path` resulting in the string `C:\some\windows\path\foo\path` without having to escape the backslashes or resort to a multi-line heredoc.

```
puts "C:\some\windows\path\#{ruby_var}\path"
puts "C:\some\windows\path\path_#{ruby_var}\path"
=> C: omewindowspath#{ruby_var}path
=> C: omewindowspathpath_foopath

puts 'C:\some\windows\path\#{ruby_var}\path'
puts 'C:\some\windows\path\path_#{ruby_var}\path'
=> C:\some\windows\path\#{ruby_var}\path
=> C:\some\windows\path\path_#{ruby_var}\path

puts %{C:\some\windows\path\#{ruby_var}\path}
puts %{C:\some\windows\path\path_#{ruby_var}\path}
=> C: omewindowspath#{ruby_var}path
=> C: omewindowspathpath_foopath

puts %q{C:\some\windows\path\#{ruby_var}\path}
puts %q{C:\some\windows\path\path_#{ruby_var}\path}
=> C:\some\windows\path\#{ruby_var}\path
=> C:\some\windows\path\path_#{ruby_var}\path
```

Comment: Have you tried using forward slashes instead? AFAIK Windows usually doesn't care which one you use.

Comment: I think I can guess what your desired output is, but perhaps you can include it in your question, just to make it clear?

Comment: `str11 = 'C:\some\windows\path\%{ruby_var}\path' % {ruby_var: "foo"}` for your collection

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
ruby_var = "hello"
puts 'C:\some\windows\path\%s\path' % ruby_var
#=>C:\some\windows\path\hello\path
```

Comment: In *theory* there's also ERB. `puts ERB.new('C:\some\<%= ruby_var %>\other').result(binding)`

Comment: Is there a term for this syntax? Something I can google for further information?

Comment: Searched for "ruby printf string syntax" and found enough to go on. Thanks again steenslag & megas!

Answer (score 4):

```
'C:\some\windows\path\%s\path' % ruby_var
#=> 'C:\some\windows\path\foo\path'
```

Comment: steenslag got in one minute before you, so I accepted his answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is possible.

You should consider using forward slashes instead to make it look prettier; I believe the standard ruby libraries in Windows won't care what kind of slashes you use.

There is also:

```
File.join('C:', 'path', ruby_var)
```